# Orthonormal basis Parsevals identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $O={u_1,...,u_k}$ be an orthonormal set in $V$. Prove that $O$ is an orthonormal basis if and only if Parseval's identity holds for all $v,w \in V$ i.e if and only if

$$\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \langle v,u_i\rangle\bar{\langle w,u_i\rangle}$$

(where $\bar{\langle w,u_i\rangle}$ is the conjugate of $\langle w,u_i\rangle$).

I've shown that if $O$ is an orthonormal basis then the identity holds but I'm having trouble with the converse. I thought maybe an argument by contradiction (assume $O$ does not span $S$ and show that the identity does not hold then assume $O$ is not linearly independent and find a contradiction) might work but I'm not sure where to start. Any thoughts?

Comment: Checking that a basis is orthonormal is just a matter of showing that it satisfies certain relations under the inner product, but Parseval's Identity says exactly that the inner product satisfies a certain identity. What does this suggest?

Comment: You're referring to the condition that $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle$is 1 if i=j and 0 otherwise? Since we already know that O is an orthonormal set we can assume that this holds so we still need to prove linear independence and the spanning condition for it to be a basis? Or am I missing something that doesn't require us to prove it this way?

Comment: Yes, that's the condition. In the converse you *conclude* that the basis is orthonormal given Parseval's identity. (Notice that the condition you mention forces linear independence.)